# Use hyper crate Body as Future crate Stream parameter

Tags: rust, hyper

Using the [hyper crate](https://crates.io/crates/hyper), I'm making an HTTP request to an endpoint then subsequently attempting to pass the response Body to a third-party library that expects a parameter to be a [Futures crate Stream](https://crates.io/crates/futures).

This results in a type error.

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
bytes = "1.0.1"
http = "0.2.3"
tokio = { version = "1.1.0", features = ["full"] }
hyper = { version = "0.14.2", features = ["full"] }
hyper-tls = "0.5.0"
futures = "0.3.12"
```

**Example**

```rust
use std::io;
use bytes::Bytes;
use hyper::{Client, Body};
use hyper_tls::HttpsConnector;
use http::Request;
use futures::stream::Stream;

// ---- begin third-party library
type ConsumableStream = dyn Stream<Item = Result<Bytes, io::Error>> + Send + Sync + 'static;
async fn stream_consumer(_: &mut ConsumableStream) {
    // consume stream...
}
// ---- end third-party library

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let uri = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    let https = HttpsConnector::new();
    let client = Client::builder().build::<_, Body>(https);
    let request = Request::get(uri).body(Body::empty()).unwrap();
    let response = client.request(request).await.unwrap();
    let mut body = Box::new(response.into_body());
    stream_consumer(&mut body).await;
}
```

**Cargo Run Output**

```sh
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<std::boxed::Box<hyper::body::body::Body> as futures_core::stream::Stream>::Item == std::result::Result<bytes::bytes::Bytes, std::io::Error>`
  --> src/bin/future_streams.rs:24:21
   |
24 |     stream_consumer(&mut body).await;
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::io::Error`, found struct `hyper::error::Error`
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::result::Result<_, std::io::Error>`
              found enum `std::result::Result<_, hyper::error::Error>`
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `(dyn futures_core::stream::Stream<Item = std::result::Result<bytes::bytes::Bytes, std::io::Error>> + std::marker::Send + std::marker::Sync + 'static)`

error: aborting due to previous error; 1 warning emitted

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0271`.
error: could not compile `rustest`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

**Question**

What's the most efficient way to use the hyper Body with as a function parameter of expected Future Stream type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConsumableStream` is expecting an `Result<Bytes, io::Error>`, but `client.request` returns a `Result<Bytes, hyper::Error>`. If `ConsumableStream` is from a third party library and you can't change the type definition, you can map the result stream:

```rust
use futures::TryStreamExt;
use std::io;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // ...
    let body = response
        .into_body()
        .map_err(|e| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, e));
    stream_consumer(&mut Box::new(body)).await;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, OK! So in the event there is a result with error, the `.map_err` function will allow you to redefine the error. This works well, thank you!